# Problems with bcp output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I have some problems with the following code. Main reason for this code is to export the SQL statement into a file. But it doesn't work and I don't see my mistake.

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE @period VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE @SQLEXE VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE @SearchSchema VARCHAR(5000);

SET @period = '''2017-01-01 00:00:00'' AND ''2017-12-31 23:59:59'''


SET @DBName = (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases where name LIKE '%NAV%');
EXECUTE ('USE [' + @DBName+']');

SET @SearchSchema  =  REPLACE((SELECT name FROM sys.tables where name LIKE '%$Change Log Setup'), 'Change Log Setup', 'Change Log Entry');
SET @SQLEXE = 'bcp "SELECT [Entry No_]
      ,[Date and Time]
      ,[User ID]
      ,[Table No_]
      ,[Field No_]
      ,[Type of Change]
      ,[Old Value]
      ,[New Value]
      ,[Primary Key]
      ,[Primary Key Field 1 No_]
      ,[Primary Key Field 1 Value]
      ,[Primary Key Field 2 Value]
      ,[Primary Key Field 3 No_]
      ,[Primary Key Field 3 Value]
      ,[Record ID]
  FROM [dbo].[' + @SearchSchema + ']
  WHERE [Date and Time] BETWEEN '+@period+'" out "C:\Users\Public\Documents\1a_EY_change_log_entry.txt" -o "C:\Users\Public\Documents\1b_EYlog_change_log_entry.log" -c -T';
Exec master..xp_cmdshell @SQLEXE;
```

The error message is:
[image]

Do you see my mistake?

Comment: Instead of `out` you need to use `queryout`, because you are trying to get data from query not from view or table. That's one thing. I am still not sure about `-o`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be weird but it will work..

Put the entire sql in single line instead of new lines

```
SET @SQLEXE = 'bcp "SELECT [Entry No_],[Date and Time],[User ID],[Table No_],[Field No_],[Type of Change],[Old Value],[New Value],[Primary Key],[Primary Key Field 1 No_],[Primary Key Field 1 Value],[Primary Key Field 2 Value],[Primary Key Field 3 No_],[Primary Key Field 3 Value],[Record ID] FROM [dbo].[' + @SearchSchema + '] WHERE [Date and Time] BETWEEN '+@period+'" out "C:\Users\Public\Documents\1a_EY_change_log_entry.txt" -o "C:\Users\Public\Documents\1b_EYlog_change_log_entry.log" -d '+quotename(@dname)+' -c -T';
```

Also this will not work as you are expecting

```
EXECUTE ('USE [' + @DBName+']');
```

Use the database parameter(`-d`) option present in `bcp`

```
-d databasename
```

Comment: The result is now:
(No column name)
master

output
NULL

Print command: PRINT 'Show: ' + @SQLEXE ;
doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to exec, you should **print** the command you get: `print @SQLEXE;`

You have at least 1 logical error: when you execute `EXECUTE ('USE [' + @DBName+']');` it changes db context **only for a duration of this your dynamic code**,

so if you try this: `EXECUTE ('USE [' + @DBName+']'); select db_name()`
you'll see that you are still in your db, not in `@DBName` context

Then your `@SearchSchema` probably remains `NULL` and this means `@SQLEXE` also becomes null.

But if your output is basic bcp usage syntax probably your command is not null but contains any other error that only you can see doing `print @SQLEXE;`.

For example it may be that you exec your code in the context of user default database (that is probably `master`) because you don't put your dbname in your code: `select..from [dbo].[' + @SearchSchema + ']` but if you don't precise the database it will be user's default database.

So post here the output of `PRINT` so we can help you more precisely

Comment: The result is now:
(No column name)
master

output
NULL

Print command: PRINT 'Show: ' + @SQLEXE ;
doesn't show anything.

Comment: >>>The result is now: (No column name) master<<< That is what I was talking about: when you change the db context within you dynamic code, as sooon as the dynamic code finishes you are still in the context of initial db, master in your case

Comment: >>>`PRINT 'Show: ' + @SQLEXE ;` doesn't show anything<<< that is because your `@SQLEXE` is null and you should correct it

Comment: After you set your `@SearchSchema`: `SET @SearchSchema  =  REPLACE((SELECT name FROM sys.tables where name LIKE '%$Change Log Setup'), 'Change Log Setup', 'Change Log Entry');` do the select of this: `SELECT @SearchSchema`, I think it's NULL