# bcp Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have problems with the error message "Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'."
Target is to extract data files from a database to a server.The problems seems to be in the queryfile. But I don't know where.

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE @period VARCHAR(5000);
DECLARE @SQLEXE VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @SearchSchema NVARCHAR(4000);


SET @period = '''2017-01-01 00:00:00'' AND ''2017-12-31 23:59:59'''


SET @DBName = (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases where name LIKE '%NAV%');
EXECUTE ('USE [' + @DBName+']'); Select db_name();

SET @SearchSchema = (SELECT REPLACE(name,'Change Log Setup', 'Change Log Entry') as Name  FROM [Demo Database NAV (10-0)].sys.tables where name LIKE '%$Change Log Setup');
PRINT '@SearchSchema: ' + @SearchSchema;



SET @SQLEXE = 'bcp SELECT [Entry No_]
      ,[Date and Time]
      ,[User ID]
      ,[Table No_]
      ,[Field No_]
      ,[Type of Change]
      ,[Old Value]
      ,[New Value]
      ,[Primary Key]
      ,[Primary Key Field 1 No_]
      ,[Primary Key Field 1 Value]
      ,[Primary Key Field 2 Value]
      ,[Primary Key Field 3 No_]
      ,[Primary Key Field 3 Value]
      ,[Record ID]
  FROM [' + @DBName + '].[dbo].[' + @SearchSchema + ']
  WHERE [Date and Time] BETWEEN '+@period+' queryout C:\Users\Public\Documents\1a_EY_change_log_entry.txt -c-T'
  PRINT 'SQLEXE ' + @SQLEXE;

Exec  (@SQLEXE);
```

The output of Print @SQLEXE ist:

```
SQLEXE bcp SELECT [Entry No_]
      ,[Date and Time]
      ,[User ID]
      ,[Table No_]
      ,[Field No_]
      ,[Type of Change]
      ,[Old Value]
      ,[New Value]
      ,[Primary Key]
      ,[Primary Key Field 1 No_]
      ,[Primary Key Field 1 Value]
      ,[Primary Key Field 2 Value]
      ,[Primary Key Field 3 No_]
      ,[Primary Key Field 3 Value]
      ,[Record ID]
  FROM [Demo Database NAV (10-0)].[dbo].[CRONUS International Ltd_$Change Log Entry]
  WHERE [Date and Time] BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-12-31 23:59:59' queryout C:\Users\Public\Documents\1a_EY_change_log_entry.txt -c-T
```

Error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'.
```

If I change the command into

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell @SQLEXE;
GO
```

the result is:

> Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.

```
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
  [-d database name]        [-K application intent]  [-l login timeout]
```

NULL

Comment: `EXEC` will execute some SQL code, not run a command line.

Comment: This post is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073064/problems-with-bcp-output/45073531?noredirect=1#comment77233470_45073531, the author is the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with bcp output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073064/problems-with-bcp-output)

Comment: Hi the change of the command did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:
 1. Use -S to determine the server you need (instead MS SQL is searching)
 2. Everything must be written in one row (because of the command line interpretation)
 3. "" can be used for query but not for the path

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell @SQLEXE;  
GO
```

Instead of `EXEC`

BCP utility runs in the context of command line.